# Windows Event implementation in Linux using conditional variables?

Tags: c++, linux, multithreading, synchronization, mutex

I am trying to implement very simple Windows events in Linux. Only for my scenario - 3 threads, 1 main and 2 secondary. Each of secondary threads raise 1 event by SetEvent and main thread wait it. Example:

```
int main()
{
    void* Events[2];
    Events[0] = CreateEvent();
    Events[1] = CreateEvent();

    pthread_start(Thread, Events[0]);
    pthread_start(Thread, Events[1]);

    WaitForMultipleObjects(2, Events, 30000) // 30 seconds timeout

    return 0;
}

int* thread(void* Event)
{
    // Do something
    SetEvent(Event);
    // Do something
}
```

So, to implement it, i use conditional variables. But my question is - is this a right way? Or i doing something wrong? My implementation:

```
// Actually, this function return pointer to struct with mutex and cond
// here i just simplified example
void* CreateEvent(mutex, condition)
{
    pthread_mutex_init(mutex, NULL);
    pthread_cond_init(condition, NULL);
}

bool SetEvent (mutex, condition)
{
    pthread_mutex_lock(mutex);
    pthread_cond_signal(condition);
    pthread_mutex_unlock(mutex);
}

int WaitForSingleObject(mutex, condition, timeout)
{
    pthread_mutex_lock(mutex);
    pthread_cond_timedwait(condition, mutex, timeout);
    pthread_mutex_unlock(mutex);
}

// Call WaitForSingleObject for each event. 
// Yes, i know, that its a wrong way, but it should work in my example.
int WaitForMultipleObjects(count, mutex[], condition[], timeout);
```

And all seems good, but i think, that problem will appear when i call WaitFor.. function in Main thread before SetEvent in secondary thread will be called. In Windows, it worked well, but in Linux - only idea is described above.

Maybe you tell me the better way to solve it? Thank you.

**UPD:** Timeout is very important, because one of the secondary threads may not pass SetEvent().

Comment: We have an open source (MIT-licensed) library called `pevents` which implements WIN32 manual and auto-reset events on linux, and includes both WaitForSingleObject and WaitForMultipleObjects clones: https://github.com/NeoSmart/PEvents

Comment: possible duplicate of [pthread-like windows manual-reset event](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/178114/pthread-like-windows-manual-reset-event)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There was similar question on stackoverflow already: [WaitForSingleObject and WaitForMultipleObjects equivalent in linux](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2719580/waitforsingleobject-and-waitformultipleobjects-equivalent-in-linux)

In addition you can use semaphores:

```
sem_t semOne  ;
sem_t semTwo  ;
sem_t semMain ;
```

In main thread:

```
sem_init(semOne,0,0) ;
sem_init(semTwo,0,0) ;
sem_init(semMain,0,0) ;

...


sem_wait(&semMain);

// Thread 1
sem_wait(&semOne);
sem_post(&semMain);


// Thread 2
sem_wait(&semTwo);
sem_post(&semMain);
```

Detailed description and various examples could be found here: ------http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/linux/library/l-ipc2lin3/index.html

The previous link is no longer available. The most recent archived version at The Internet Archive's Wayback Machine is:
https://web.archive.org/web/20130515223326/http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/linux/library/l-ipc2lin3/index.html

Comment: Thank you, but what about timeout? As i know, semaphores doesn't have it.

Comment: You could simply use sem_timedwait() instead of sem_wait().

Comment: I think, that semaphores can't timedwait... Thank you )

Comment: Why they can't wait? There are some bugs regarding sem_timewait(). You can find some clues [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1832395/sem-timedwait-not-supported-properly-on-redhat-enterprise-linux-5-3-onwards) or [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2928571/ubuntu-sem-timedwait-not-waking-c).

Answer (score 4):

Basing this on the description of [`WaitForSingleObject`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms687032%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)

> The *WaitForSingleObject* function checks the current state of the specified object. If the object's state is nonsignaled, the calling thread enters the wait state until the object is signaled or the time-out interval elapses.

The difference between that behavior and the code is that the code will always wait on the condition variable, as it does not check a predicate.  This introduces synchronization issues between the `pthread_condt_timewait` and `pthread_cond_signal` calls.

The general idiom for signalling a condition variable is:

```
lock mutex
set predicate
unlock mutex
signal condition variable
```

And when waiting for a condition variable:

```
lock mutex
while ( !predicate )
{ 
  wait on condition variable
}
unlock mutex
```

Based on what is trying to be accomplished, a separate `bool` could be used as a predicate for each `Event`.  By introducing a predicate, `WaitForSingleObject` should only wait on the condition variable if the `Event` has not been signaled.  The code would look similar to the following:

```
bool SetEvent (mutex, condition)
{
    pthread_mutex_lock(mutex);                 // lock mutex
    bool& signalled = find_signal(condition);  // find predicate
    signalled = true;                          // set predicate
    pthread_mutex_unlock(mutex);               // unlock mutex
    pthread_cond_signal(condition);            // signal condition variable
}

int WaitForSingleObject(mutex, condition, timeout)
{
    pthread_mutex_lock(mutex);                         // lock mutex
    bool& signalled = find_signal(condition);          // find predicate
    while (!signalled)
    {
      pthread_cond_timedwait(condition, mutex, timeout);
    }
    signalled = false;                                 // reset predicate
    pthread_mutex_unlock(mutex);                       // unlock mutex
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think semaphore is a better solution here, because it can be used inter-process.
You can wrap the interface, if name is not provide, then use pthread_ to initialize it for intra-process to use, which can short the resource usage, but when name used, try to use sem initialize it, for intra-process use.